# How to pack javascript files in laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am using Laravel `5.3`,
I want to pack all the javascript files，in file `app.js`,I require() `tether` and `cropper`  like this:
：

```
require('tether');// `tether` is put at the head of `Bootstrap`
require('./bootstrap');

require('cropper');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: 'body'
});
```

Then running `gulp`，it's ok!
But in console of chrome broswer,there are 2 errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether
Uncaught TypeError: $image.cropper is not a function
```

Why is it？

PS:

`bootstrap` not `Bootstrap`，there is a file `bootstrap.js` in `resources/assets/js`,and  `Bootstrap` is the UI of Twitter.

Comment: Did you try `import Tether from 'tether'; window.Tether = Tether;`?

Comment: @Skysplit Thanks,that issue has been solved.Another error appears: `[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: body `

Comment: @zwl1619 Are you using Vue 2.0?

Comment: @Gerard Reches yes, Vue 2.0.

Comment: @zwl1619 Then you must create a wrapper div with an id. `<body><div id="app">Your page</div></body>` and change `el: 'body'` to `el: '#app'`. In Vue 2.0 `html` or `body` can't be used for `el`.

Comment: @zwl1619 won't you mind if I post my comment as an answer?

Comment: @Skysplit  I won't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I have written in comments, the solution is following code:

```
import Tether from 'tether'

window.Tether = Tether;
```